# Is it possible to merge two json responses using nginx?

Tags: json, nginx, microservices, api-design, content-negotiation

I have an existing express endpoint that looks like this:

```
app.get(`${route}/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const result = await dbFn(id);
        res.send(result);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).end();
    }
});
```

And this is going to return an object that  looks like:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Foo"
}
```

Now, I want to extend this API, so that if it has a `Accept: application/vnd.v2` header, then it will also fetch some data from a different service, and add that on. ([See my related question where using content negotiation is suggested](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390956/are-different-endpoints-to-display-the-same-resource-in-different-ways-restful)).

ie. the response will be:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Foo", 
    "extraData": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Now, I can do this with express, here's how I have done it:

```
  app.get(`${route}/:id`, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

      const id = req.params.id;
      const jobSeeker = await dbFn(id);
      if (req.accepts("application/vnd.v2")) {
        const response = await axios.get(`${integrationApiPath}/connection/${id}`); 
        const ssiData = response.data; 

        res.send({
          ...jobSeeker, 
          ssiData
        })

      }
      else {
        res.send(jobSeeker);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).end();
    }

  });
```

But it struck me as a bit of a messy way to do API versioning.

What would be much nicer, is if I can have nginx handling this versioning instead.

That way, I don't need to modify my existing API, I can just create the new service, and have nginx examine the headers, and make both microservice calls and join them together.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> But it struck me as a bit of a messy way to do API versioning.

I don't think that this is a bad way to do API versioning, since it's a common way to do it. In addition you can serve the new service in a new subdirectory (e.g. yourwebsite.com/yourservice.../**v2**/yourFunction).

> What would be much nicer, is if I can have nginx handling this versioning instead.

I also don't agree that it would be nicer to let NginX do the "logic" of your webservice, since it's the responsibility of NginX to serve your website/webservice, not to implement the logic.

However, if you still want to merge the requests using NginX you may want to have a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267497/is-it-possible-to-consolidate-multiple-responses-and-send-one-response-in-nginx). This answer uses [openresty](https://openresty.org/en/). You may have to [install this](https://openresty.org/en/installation.html) first.

As described, you can call multiple (in your case 2) services using this code:

```
location /yourServiceV2 {
    content_by_lua_block {
        local respA = ngx.location.capture("/yourService")
        local respB = ngx.location.capture("/theServiceWhichExtendsYourService")

        ngx.say(respA.body .. respB.body)
    }
}
```

If you only want to perform the mentioned code under when a specific header is present you can use a `if` statement like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970620/nginx-reject-request-if-header-is-not-present-or-wrong). So, your `if` statement would look like this:

```
if ($http_accept == 'application/vnd.v2') {
    return 405;
}
```

Comment: This would be executing `A` then `B` yes? This seems strictly worse than doing it at a layer you can run these requests in parallel I think.

Comment: An example of doing the above in parallel is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948017/is-there-a-way-to-configure-nginx-to-broadcast-incoming-requests-to-multiple-ups